# Como gerar JSON dinamicamente para alimentar futura aplicação?

Tags: api, rest, back-end, getjson

O que quero fazer é seguinte: Criar uma aplicação minimalista que faz uma busca no banco de dados, retorna o resultado em JSON, e este resultado é interpretado por aplicações externas via http, sem alteração na aplicação minimalista. Funciona como uma API, mas o intuito de servir de modelo de construção para outras APIs.
Até o momento, consegui gerar o JSON com sucesso após criar o CRUD. O problema começa quando quero consumir o resultado desta consulta. Não consigo fazer o arquivo selectTabela.php servir de consumo. Quero reprocessar a informação em diferentes formatos, tanto pelo getjson do Jquery, quanto objetos de PHP. Segue código de arquivos.

**selectTabela.php**

```
    <?php header('Content-Type:' . "text/plain");
   // Testando classe CRUD
   /*  
    * Require nos scripts necessários  
    */   
require_once "control/config.php";
require_once "control/controleCentral.php";   
require_once "control/validaEntradas.php";
require_once "model/crud.class.php"; 
include "view/viewsRetornos.php"; 
   /*  
    * Atribui uma instância da classe crud   
    * e passa uma conexão como parâmetro  
    */   
   $crud = crud::getInstance(Conexao::getInstance());
    /*  
    * Variáveis contendo os valores para serem inseridos no banco de dados  
    */    
//$crud->delete(17);



 $dados = $crud->getAlltabela($dbTabela); // para todos da tabela
  if ($controleSelectTotal = true) {
     if ($controleSelectTotal != false) {
      echo '{"'."dados".'"'.":[";
    foreach ($dados as $reg): 
       $id = $reg->id ;
       $varchar1 = $reg->varchar1;
       $$varchar2 = $reg->varchar2;
      retornaSelectTotal($id, $varchar1, $$varchar2);// Função que retorna visualmente na tela os dados
      endforeach; 
      echo ' 
{
        "Id": "0",
        "Categoria": "00000",
        "Titulo": "000000"
      }


      ]}';
  } 
  }


  ?>
```

**jsonPHP.php**

```
<?php 
$arquivo = "selectTabela.php";

$info = file_get_contents($arquivo);
// Eu sei... eu sei....ele vai cuspir o conteúdo do PHP ao invés do JSON.
/* Relaxa que eu estou ciente. Mas não sei como escapar só o resultado deste arquivo.
Repare que eu tentei declarar 'header('Content-Type:' . "text/plain");' no início do PHP*/

$lendo = json_decode($info);

foreach($lendo->dados as $campo){

echo "<b>id:</b> ".$campo->id;
echo "<br /><b>categoria:</b> ".$campo->Categoria;
echo "<br /><b>titulo:</b> ".$campo->titulo;

}



?>
```

**via JavaScript**

```
// Classe para chamar o Json.
function json(){
    var qtd;
    var retorno;

    // Resgatar valores.
    json.prototype.resgatarValores = function(){
        $('#resultado').html('Carregando dados...');

        // Estrutura de resultado.
        $.getJSON('../jsonPHP.php', function(data){
            this.qtd = data.dados.length;
            this.retorno = '';

            for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){
                this.retorno += 'ID: ' + data.dados[i].id + '<br />';
                this.retorno += 'Categoria: ' + data.dados[i].Categoria + ' - ';
                this.retorno += 'titulo: ' + data.dados[i].titulo + '<br /><br />';
            }

            $('#resultado').html(this.retorno);
        });

    }

}

// Objeto.
var obj = new json();
obj.resgatarValores();
```

Para titulo de curiosidade, quando salvo um arquivo JSON (que não é o que quero) e aponto para estes scripts, tudo funciona normalmente. Mas lembrando, não é o que estou querendo. Quero gerar o json dinamicamente. 
Se alguém quiser testar, segue abaixo:

```
{"dados":[{"id":"1","Categoria":"JoÃƒÂ£o Carlos","titulo":"joca"},{"id":"5","Categoria":"Pedro Henrique","titulo":"maria@email.com"},{"id":"7","Categoria":"Carlos Manuel","titulo":"carlos@hotmail.com"},{"id":"8","Categoria":"Carlos Manuel2","titulo":"carlos@hotmail.com"},{"id":"9","Categoria":"Novo Manuel","titulo":"carlos@hotmail.com"},{"id":"10","Categoria":"hackeado","titulo":"carlos@hotmail.com"}, 
{
        "Id": "0",
        "Categoria": "00000",
        "Titulo": "000000"
      }


      ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta colocar o caminho completo da URL que deseja obter a leitura do JSON no arquivo jsonPHP.php. Ao invés de fazer a include com código e tudo, isso fará com que apenas a saída HTTP do arquivo seja realizada.

Certo:

```
$arquivo = "http://localhost/novoMVC/areaDeTrabalho/selectTabela.php";
```

Errado:

```
$arquivo = "selectTabela.php";
```